# Is it possible to make an AJAX call to JavaScript instead of ASP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am making somewhat of a [content delivery network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) (CDN), but I want to have a jQuery AJAX call to a JavaScript file instead of an ASP file. The JavaScript file would then handle the input and then return a response. I don't want to use ASP, because I don't want to set up a whole server, especially because I am on a Mac. If this isn't possible that's fine, I'm just wondering.

(I can not provide any code, because I don't have enough that it would be useful.)

Comment: That makes little sense - where would the Javascript be executed, if not in the browser? And then you won't need an AJAX request in the first place.

Comment: It's not really a question that is easy to answer? A CDN is not something you make with javascript, and making an ajax call to get a javascript file is certainly doable, but why do you need it, and what are you expecting should happen when you get that javascript file etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use AJAX to retrieve a JavaScript file, that's *kinda* possible.  You'll just need to dynamically add a `<script>` tag to the page (with the URL of the JS file in question) and the browser will take care of the rest.  Don't forget you can add an `onload` handler to execute some code when the file's loaded.

If, however, you wanted to run JavaScript on your server, there's the excellent [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) for that.  You *will* need to have another server running in this case.

Either way, there's not really a way to have code running outside of the browser and not have a separate server.  Hope this helps, comment with any further questions.

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if you're just trying to lazy load a JavaScript file from a URL, but that isn't your question, so I'll ignore that.

You *can* do just about anything, but that doesn't mean you should. You can't directly make an Ajax call to JavaScript. That's just a meaningless statement... The semantics of what you actually said would require an Ajax call to a server that has the ability to execute JavaScript code like a browser would, which can be done with a headless browser like [PhantomJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PhantomJS). So, you would have to install PhantomJS on your server, Ajax to the server, have the server use PhantomJS to process some JavaScript code, then have the server respond to the Ajax call with whatever result you come up with.

I have to reiterate: **You should not do this ^.**

It would be like traveling the world to get to your neighbor's house. Anything that is possible within all of that mess, you could have just done it in the JavaScript code on the page or on the server in the server-side language.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was insane, but I was just curious